# Use right() function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to get dates (like 000,001...999..n), when I use `right()` function from while loop with select it works fine. If I assign it to variable result is different.

```
DECLARE @cnt_chr INT = 1;
DECLARE @cnt_num INT = 1;
DECLARE @num varchar;
DECLARE @chr varchar;
DECLARE @full varchar;
WHILE @cnt_num <= 999 
BEGIN
    select RIGHT(CONCAT('000', CONVERT(varchar, @cnt_num)), 3);
    SET @cnt_num = @cnt_num + 1;

END;
```

If I write after begin like this:

```
        @num = RIGHT(CONCAT('000', CONVERT(varchar, @cnt_num)), 3); 
        SET @cnt_num = @cnt_num + 1;
        print @num;
```

results are different. What might be a cause?

Comment: Ok, what is your problem

Comment: DECLARE @num varchar(5); you need to declare varchar with a length.

Comment: @Jermy, there is no need to declare varchar length. But in that case the default length is 1.

Comment: Problem is when i try to assign it to variable @num, result is not what i expect. Maybe there is wrong assign to variable..I need use result of loop. So what can I do?

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic technically you are correct. default length is 1, which is why he needs to declare it with a length in order to get a correct result.

Comment: @Jermy I agree completely!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a `varchar` with a length e.g.

```
DECLARE @num varchar(5);
```